# I have a very basic react program, but it's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I tried a very basic react program, in which I have three `button` with something written on it, and whenever someone clicks it, my `h1` tag should show that value of the `button` that was clicked.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.state = {
      title: '',
    }
  }
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({title: e.currentTarget.value}, () => console.log(this.state.title))
  }
  render(){
    return <div className = 'container'>
    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
    <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Hello World</button>
    <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Bye World</button>
    <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Good Bye World</button>
    </div>
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I logged my event, I saw that the value of `event.currentTarget.name` is set to "current target" (which is strange) and target value is `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instant change the `e.currentTarget.value` to `e.target.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of a button is determined by its `value` attribute and the `name` but the `name` attribute. Your buttons do not have `value` *or* `name` attributes.

Possibly you are looking for `e.currentTarget.textContent`?

Comment: I tried, e.currentTarget.textContent, but still same result. My h1 value is not getting rendered.

Comment: @MayBeNextT1me — Then you must have changed something else. [It works fine when I test it](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-u3ruu?file=/index.js).

Comment: huh, but what's the difference between value and textContent? I have been using value in a lot of my projects and it works just fine

Comment: @MayBeNextT1me — I explained what the value is in the first sentence of the answer. The `textContent` is the text content of the element (as the name suggests).

Comment: So you mean that if I want to use currentTarget.value then there must be a value tag, and if I want the textContent, then I just use currentTarget.textContent, right?

Comment: If you want a value, then you need a `value` *attribute* (`<button value="something">`) not a `value` *tag* which would be `<value>` except that HTML has no such thing.

Comment: Yup, my bad, I meant attribute, not tag. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

replace `e.currentTarget.value` with `e.currentTarget.innerText` and you will be fine.

Comment: Do a console.dir(e.currentTarget) and you will find that value is not getting populated. In vanilla js i acquire the element content through innerHTML, innerText or textContent. I use value when I have to extract it from forms or input fields.